# Как изменить высоту между строками <br>?

Tags: html, css

Есть текст, который выводится при помощи php-функции nl2br().

Меня не устраивает слишком большой отступ между `<br><br>` текстом, то есть когда идёт 2 переноса строки подряд, но при этом меня устраивает line-height блока с этим текстом, а это, как я понял, единственный способ изменить высоту между строками. Как можно поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: не совсем понятно, что конкретно вы хотите. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос с примерами того, что вы хотите и что не получается

Comment: замените два переноса на один? пару `br` чаще ставят, когда  надо отступ между абзацами имитировать, но для этих целей есть `<p>`

Comment: как вариант `br + br {line-height: ... }` для второго подряд идущего `br` можно задать.

Comment: teran, если "окружающий" текст не "в тегах", то так правило будет применяться ко всем `<br />` кроме самого первого

Answer (score 5):

Можно изменить отступы при помощи css

```
 br{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `padding` в `br`.
пишем так:

```
<head>
    <style>
        br{
        padding: Xpx;<!-- X это число-->
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте `span` после `br` с любым классом, скажем, `.br` и управляйте им через CSS.