# Как изменить свойства двух подряд идущих тегов?

Tags: html, css

Как изменить свойства ТОЛЬКО выделенных двух br идущих подряд между текстом или второму идущему за первым (так же только из выделенных синим). Если между тегами есть текст, правила применяться не должны.

[image: разметка с выделенными тегами]

<sup>Связанный вопрос: [Как изменить высоту между строками <br>?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/681030)</sup>

Comment: Что это? Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: можно за каждый 2-й вцепиться 
css : 
br + br {
}

Comment: @МузыкаСергей не подойдет, br + br будет браться и за тот который идёт через строку, а нужно именно 2 br подряд

Answer (score 0):

Думал что это невозможно, но вроде нашел "хак"

Проверил в Chrome desctop, FF и IE11, остальные сами смотрите)

```css
br {
  /* 
    судя по всему <br /> выступает в качестве псевдо-элемента, 
    по-этому меняем символ переноса строки на пустое значение.
    p.s. разумеется это не относится к IE 
  */
  content: ''; 
  /* делаем его блочным */
  display: block;
  /* и нулевой высоты (то есть без отступов, высота и так 0) */
  margin: 0;
}
  /* 
    грязным хаком выбираем IE9+.
    для младших версий добавте селекторы по необходимости.
    ТАК ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ СТОИТ, но если надо....
  */
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution: +72dpi) {
  br { margin: -1em; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  1111111
  <br />
  2111111
  <br />
  <br />
  3111111
  <br />
  <br />
  4111111
  4222222
  4333333
  <br />
  5111111
  <br />
  <br />
  6111111
  6222222
  <br />
  <br />
  7111111
</div>
```